Connection refused error when trying to send an email using nodemailer
I am trying to send a mail from node using nodemailer. I tried to send using ethereal for testing, but i keep getting connection refused error.
const createAutoEmail = require("../functionLib/autoEmail");

const config = {
  type: "service",
  host: "smtp.ethereal.email",
  port: 587,
  secure:false,
  auth: {
    user: "rylan.kshlerin57@ethereal.email",
    pass: "Sg7f8z2r2Yyhs8hppZ",
  },
  defaultFrom: "no-reply@example.com",
  templates: {
    welcome: {
      subject: `Welcome to our Community`,
      body: `<h1>Hi {{name}}</h1><p>Thanks for joining our community. We are happy to have you here.</p>`,
    },
  },
  schedules: {},
};

async function test() {
  const autoEmailer = createAutoEmail(config);
  await autoEmailer.initialize();

  // Check if the 'welcome' template exists
  if (!config.templates.welcome) {
    console.error("Template 'welcome' not found in config.");
    return;
  }

  try {
    await autoEmailer.sendScheduledEmail("welcome", "recipient@example.com", {
      name: "John",
    });
    console.log("Email sent successfully");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error sending email:", error);
  }

  autoEmailer.shutdown();
}

test();


I tried to execute like this.when i run this file i keep getting error message.
This is my first time using nodemailer and i am not able to find the error in it.
